# Jackrabbit repository could not be accessed from karaf container

Tags: osgi, apache-camel, jackrabbit

I  am trying to access a jackrabbit repository through rmi from karaf container

I developped a camel route  which save a file into  jackrabbit repository

```
<bean id="repository"
    class="org.apache.jackrabbit.rmi.repository.URLRemoteRepository">
    <argument value="http://localhost:8020/rmi" />
</bean>


<camelContext id="blueprintContext" trace="false"
    xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
    <route id="depotfichiersurjcr">


        <from uri="file:/C:/data?recursive=false&amp;noop=true" />
        <!-- log message="message1 ${body}"/ -->
        <setHeader headerName="CamelJcrNodeName">
            <constant>node</constant>
        </setHeader>
        <setHeader headerName="my.contents.property">
            <simple>${bodyAs(String)}</simple>
            <!-- constant>content</constant -->
        </setHeader>
        <setBody>
            <constant></constant>
        </setBody>
        <to  uri="jcr://admin:admin@repository/default?deep=true&eventTypes=3&noLocal=false" />
        <to uri="direct:a" />
    </route>

</camelContext>
```

the route works fine with mvn camel:run

the same route doesnt work inside the karaf container , i got :

---

javax.jcr.RepositoryException: Remote repository not found: The resource at http://localhost:8020/rmi could not be retrieved
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.rmi.repository.URLRemoteRepositoryFactory.getRemoteRepository(URLRemoteRepositoryFactory.java:84)[1626:org.apache.jackrabbit.jackrabbit-jcr-rmi:2.6.2]
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.rmi.repository.AbstractRemoteRepositoryFactory.getRepository(AbstractRemoteRepositoryFactory.java:57)[1626:org.apache.jackrabbit.jackrabbit-jcr-rmi:2.6.2]
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.rmi.repository.ProxyRepository.login(ProxyRepository.java:199)[1626:org.apache.jackrabbit.jackrabbit-jcr-rmi:2.6.2]
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.rmi.repository.ProxyRepository.login(ProxyRepository.java:233)[1626:org.apache.jackrabbit.jackrabbit-jcr-rmi:2.6.2]
        at com.sagemcom.Content.process(Content.java:21)[1618:content:0.0.1.SNAPSHOT]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateSyncProcessor.process(DelegateSyncProcessor.java:63)[171:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.13.2]
        at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72)[171:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.13.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:398)[171:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.13.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)[171:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.13.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:118)[171:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.13.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80)[171:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.13.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)[171:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.13.2]
        at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer.sendTimerExchange(TimerConsumer.java:157)[171:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.13.2]
        at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer$1.run(TimerConsumer.java:68)[171:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.13.2]
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)[:1.7.0_75]
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)[:1.7.0_75]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL: http://localhost:8020/rmi
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1627)[:1.7.0_75]
        at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1037)[:1.7.0_75]
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.rmi.repository.URLRemoteRepositoryFactory.getRemoteRepository(URLRemoteRepositoryFactory.java:61)[1626:org.apache.jackrabbit.jackrabbit-jcr-rmi:2.6.2]
        ... 15 more

is there any specific configurations that should be done to let the karaf container see the jackrabbit url, any suggestion will be welcome , Thanks .

Comment: I believe the issue is similar to this thread:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15233420/apache-camel-jcr-jackrabbit

Comment: Actually , the camel jcr component works fine inside  the unit test and I can  get connection to jackrabbit repository over rmi , the issue show up when I deploy  the route under the karaf container and I do not understand why the karaf container could not resolve the repository rmi URL

Answer (score 0):

In the case of the testcase the configuration is from the baseclass, which may need to be added to camel context.

Here's an example configuration from a camel example for the rmi:

```
    <bean id="rmiServer" class="java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry"     factory-method="createRegistry">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="${port}"/>

  </bean>

<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" depends-on="rmiServer">
<endpoint id="rmiService" 
uri="rmi://localhost:${port}/helloServiceBean?remoteInterfaces=org.apache.camel.example.osgi.HelloService"/> 
<!-- expose a RMI service as a Camel route -->
<camel:route> 
<from ref="rmiService"/> 
<to uri="log:Incoming request on RMI"/> 
<to uri="bean:helloServiceBean"/> 
</camel:route> </camelContext>
```

Now this is typically needed if you're using rmi.

In the case that you have just described, we need the JndiRegistry.
Can you try adding the following to the camel context

```
<bean id="registry" class="org.apache.camel.impl.JndiRegistry"/>
```

In the case of the JCR Jackrabbit try the following bean configuration:

```
    <bean id="repository"                    class="org.apache.jackrabbit.rmi.repository.URLRemoteRepository">
                <argument value="http://localhost:8020/rmi" />
  </bean>
```

Comment: I added <bean id="registry" class="org.apache.camel.impl.JndiRegistry"/> and  i got a new error    org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: jcr://admin:admin@repository/default due to: No JCR repository defined under 'repository'

Comment: Got it , since it's not a JNDI lookup and the JCR Jackrabbit has a different mechanism, we may need to inject the repository of jcr. I have updated the answer please check confirm if this works. Thanks.

Comment: am still looking for a way to resolve it, and I hope it's not an issue of camel jcr component or jackrabbit rmi library . please keep me posted if u found something usefull , thanks!